# How to write a condition for a dictionary?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have one dictionary and in this dictionary I have different keys. I want to print some of them that has one specific field for example I want to print those one with key='d'

```
{'a' : 1 ,'b' : 2, 'c' :3}
{'a': 2, 'b' : 33 , 'c' : 44 , 'd' : 56 , 'e' : 78}
{'a' : 4 ,'b' : 6, 'c' :7}
{'a': 66, 'b' : 23 , 'c' : 1 , 'd' : 3 , 'e' : 6}
```

One way is to use

```
for key in example.keys():
   if key='d':
      print example
```

But in this way I search in all key. I think it must have some easier solution without using for and if.
does any one has some points?

Comment: How are you getting `<generator object list at 0x7f7de766cc50>`? There's detail missing here

Comment: I talk to API 
I do not write other code.

Comment: How can i write condition for such dictionary

Comment: what condition are you interested in exactly? do you want to test if it has a key?

Comment: What API though? You have some object that may be a list of dictionaries, but you've also got a generator in there. Without a [mcve] I'm not sure what we can suggest

Comment: @yasinlachini do you mean the `'image_location'` field has a value of `'snapshot'`?  or `'image_type'`?  there are many ways of interpreting your question...  these sorts of details really matter to code if you're asking these sorts of questions

Comment: @SamMason   image_type is snapshot

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all the details of your problem, but if you want to get only the dictionaries with a certain key you can do the following

```
def show_images():
    for image in list_images():
        image_type = image.get("image_type", None)
        if image_type == "snapshot":
            print(image)
```

Now, if you want to see if any key has a `snapshot` value then you can do as (as suggested in a comment)

```
def show_images():
    for image in list_images():
        if "snapshot" in image.values():
            print(image)
```

Comment: it print nothing

Comment: Then there is no key `snapshot` in any of the dictionaries.

Comment: I can see it in print

Comment: @yasinlachini I'm making a guess of what you want and edited the answer. But there is more than one key that has `snapshot` as value.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def show_images():
    for image in list_images():
        for key in image.keys():
            if image[key] == "snapshot":
                print(image)
                break
```

Comment: that would be `"snapshot" in image`, no extra `for` loop needed

Comment: Going through all the keys is rather silly when you have a dictionary where you can ask for the key directly.

Comment: how can i print those image that have snapshot field?

Comment: this would print the first item twice.  `'snapshot'` is a value of two keys.  maybe `if 'snapshot' in image.values()`?